# Importing javascript into c# class

Tags: c#, javascript

I created a class in C# (Class1.cs) that uses javascript to execute some commands (JavaScript1.js).
I know that if I import this javascript into the WebForm1.ASPX (the one that uses Class1.cs), it will work.
The problem is that I want to be able to use this Class1.cs class in other WebForms. To do that, I have to import this javascript into every WebForm.
Is there a way to import it into the class?

Here is an example:

MAIN PAGE

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebApplication1"%>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.callSomething();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Test" Text ="ALERT"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CLASS

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void callSomething()
        {
            // Here I call the javascript.
        }
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function alertTest()
{
    alert('worked');
}
```

In this case I´m using:

```
<script src="JavaScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But this way, I´ll have to put this in every single webform. What I want to do is import at the class (Class1).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add a `<script src="...."/>` tag?

Comment: I know I can do that at the WebForm (.ASPX file). But I´d like to do that at the class (.cs file).

Comment: @danielu can you show as what does the Test.cs contain

Comment: Be careful how you word this. Your .NET classes and ASPX pages never have any interaction with javascript whatsoever. The most they can do is write the script or a script tag out to the response to be put into a page.

Comment: I edited the post and put a simple example of what I´m trying to do.

Comment: Extends your webforms with a base class (eg. WebForm : BasePage and BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page). Then add the script tag programmatically on Page_Load event of the base class, so you have to do this only once. Just remember to call base.Page_Load in the extended webforms' Page_Load event. This way, you could do this simple work of tag adding, but as well a lot of more common features between your pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` method will [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) you.

if you are making custom control and want to automatically load .js file with it you can add it as resource to your project:

```
 public class FancyGridView : GridView
    {

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(
                typeof(FancyGridView), "FancyCustomControls.Scripts.GridViewScript.js");
        }
...
}
```

`GridViewScript.js` needs to be added as resource(set "Embedded Resource" in it's options\build action) and add it to `AssemblyInfo`:

```
[assembly: WebResource("FancyCustomControls.Scripts.GridViewScript.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Comment: it worked perfectly for me in my custom `DatGridView` which contained only one class contained in .cs file.